# RNA Splicing Python

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have a gene sequence –

```
"acguccgcaagagaagccuuaauauauucaaaaagcuacgccucagauuucgcgcucgagcccaaaacaacugguguacggguugaucacaucaaaugaagucgcuaaagucggugaucucacuauccuugucuucggcuuuugcucucucggcuaucaucuaagcaggcgaguuccauggugaccggaacgacggcuacuggaguccaugaucgcaagcgucgggcugggguaaaagaggcucagcucauaauaguccgccccaccaguacgggacucgauaggccccgucguugccguagaaacgcaauuuuccucagacccacuauacgcaccucgauuuagcaugguuccgggguugcgcuuugagaaucauacguaaggaucggaaccuaggaaugcaccacagaacuuugaaauacuagaacaaguugauugacaacggaguaucggcgccccacauuuaacgaauaauugcaggcgccagacgaugcuaggugcguccguaucaagauucgaggucgcuacuggcuucgcuugccgaucgagcucagaguuugugagaguuguuacuaauugcguggucgccuaauauccuugauacuacguggguguacuagacaucccggacagaaaaucucuuaaacgcuagaguucucuuggaagcgccugcacuucuugugaacauacgaugauagccacucuaagcccaacgcacuucgcuuggcccacauugcccccagagcuuauucaucgacaggcguuccacucuuggauucaucaguaaacuuuauuauacgugguaagcgugcuuauagcugucggaaucucacuuaggcggauugaagugagacagccugaaaguaaccguguacaggcgccgucaauguguuuugagugugcaccuacaaaaaguguuauuuaggcaggggagcuuuguaguuucuuuagaagagccgcgaaugaaccaacgguagacugcgagcgcguucaaccuaau"
```

I want to splice the RNA and want to extract two lists (exons and introns). The key is that the intron section of RNA starts with `gu` and ends with `ag`. However, if `ag` appears before `gu`, it is a part of the exon and not the intron.

```
def splice(sequence):
    introns = list()
    exons = list()

    while(sequence.count("gu")):

        if "gu" not in sequence:
            break
        else:    

            exons.append(sequence[:sequence.find("gu")])
            sequence = sequence[sequence.find("gu"):]

        if "ag" not in sequence:
            break
        else:

            introns.append(sequence[:sequence.find("ag")+2])
            sequence = sequence[sequence.find("ag")+2:]

    return introns, exons
```

This is what I have so far. It goes well pretty far but the issue begins at the end when `gu` appears without an `ag` in the remaining string.

Output:

```
Exons:
['ac',
 'agaagccuuaauauauucaaaaagcuacgccucagauuucgcgcucgagcccaaaacaacug',
 'ucgcuaaa',
 'caggcga',
 'uccaugaucgcaagc',
 'aggcucagcucauaaua',
 'uacgggacucgauaggcccc',
 'aaacgcaauuuuccucagacccacuauacgcaccucgauuuagcaug',
 'aaucauac',
 'gaucggaaccuaggaaugcaccacagaacuuugaaauacuagaacaa',
 'uaucggcgccccacauuuaacgaauaauugcaggcgccagacgaugcuag',
 'auucgag',
 'cucaga',
 'a',
 'acaucccggacagaaaaucucuuaaacgcuaga',
 'cgccugcacuucuu',
 'ccacucuaagcccaacgcacuucgcuuggcccacauugcccccagagcuuauucaucgacaggc',
 'uaaacuuuauuauac',
 'c',
 'cu',
 'gcggauugaa',
 'acagccugaaa',
 'gcgcc',
 'u',
 'u',
 'gcaggggagcuuu',
 'uuucuuuagaagagccgcgaaugaaccaacg',
 'acugcgagcgc']

Introns:
['guccgcaag',
 'guguacggguugaucacaucaaaugaag',
 'gucggugaucucacuauccuugucuucggcuuuugcucucucggcuaucaucuaag',
 'guuccauggugaccggaacgacggcuacuggag',
 'gucgggcugggguaaaag',
 'guccgccccaccag',
 'gucguugccguag',
 'guuccgggguugcgcuuugag',
 'guaag',
 'guugauugacaacggag',
 'gugcguccguaucaag',
 'gucgcuacuggcuucgcuugccgaucgag',
 'guuugugag',
 'guuguuacuaauugcguggucgccuaauauccuugauacuacguggguguacuag',
 'guucucuuggaag',
 'gugaacauacgaugauag',
 'guuccacucuuggauucaucag',
 'gugguaag',
 'gugcuuauag',
 'gucggaaucucacuuag',
 'gugag',
 'guaaccguguacag',
 'gucaauguguuuugag',
 'gugcaccuacaaaaag',
 'guuauuuag',
 'guag',
 'guag']
```

Comment: I fixed the query by using regular expressions.

def splice(gene_Sequence):

    # Regular expression to find the sequences between 'gu' and 'ag'
    regex = r"gu(?:\w{0,}?)ag"
    introns = re.findall(regex, gene_Sequence)

    for intron in introns:
        exon = gene_Sequence.replace(intron, "")

    return introns, exon

Comment: So this fixed the issue?

Comment: @IbtihajTahir
It would be good to post your fix/answer as an answer, rather than as a comment

Comment: @ColinAnthony Okay I'm gonna do this right now.

Comment: @IbtihajTahir Great! now you can accept it as the answer! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the query by using regular expressions.

```
def splice(gene_Sequence): 

    regex = r"gu(?:\w{0,}?)ag" 
    introns = re.findall(regex, gene_Sequence) 

    for intron in introns: 
        exon = gene_Sequence.replace(intron, "") 

    return introns, exon
```